# Kali linux persistance usb is not saving anything

Tags: linux, usb, kali-linux, usb-boot

I created a kali linux usb by flash the OS(downloaded from the website and I has chosen the usb one) to the usb with etcher, then I followed the process on [kali website](https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/usb-persistence-encryption/). Nothing gives error in the process, then I booted the usb and selected the persistence encrypted one. But still nothing saved after reboot. I tried on both a sd card and a usb

Answer (score 0):

Try and find something like this in boot options (grub)

linuxefi /live/vmlinuz boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence

needs to be changed to

linuxefi /live/vmlinuz boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence persistence-encryption=luks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).